# Unable to return function parameter due to conflicting types for 'function' in C

Tags: c, function

I'm new to C and I'm trying to understand how there are conflicting types for my function "using_name".

I also don't understand why I have to include a '*' to name the 'using_name()' function. It is because I'm storing a value in the function address?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int using_name(), call_func(char name[20]);
char name[20];

int main ()
{
    using_name();
    call_func(name);

    return 0;
}

char* using_name()
{
        printf("What is your name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);
        printf("\n Your name is %s", name);

        return name;
}

int call_func(char name[20])
{
    printf("Hello %s", using_name(name));

}
```

Error: conflicting types for 'using_name'

Comment: Yeah conflicting types, `int using_name()` then `char* using_name()`.

Comment: It's a contrived example which doesn't use the return value – it's a global anyway – but the definition and the declaration must match.

Comment: It's got two return types and also two argument types: it's declared with no arguments, then called with a char * argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return and argument types in the funnction prototype at the beginning of the program has to match the actual types when the function is defined later.

Since `using_name()` is defined as:

```
char *using_name()
```

You need to change the earlier prototype to:

```
char *using_name();
int call_func(char name[20]);
```

Another solution is to just put the function definitions at the beginning of the program. You only need prototypes for functions that are used before they're defined, or functions that are defined in another compilation unit (although these prototypes are usually put in a header file).

Comment: That solved the conflicting issue but now when I run the script, I enter a name, and the first function repeats before moving to the next function. Could you help again pls

Comment: That's because you call `using_name()` twice. You call it in `main()` and again in `call_func()`.

Comment: It should just be `printf("Hello %d\n", name);`

Comment: Barmar for president!